# How would i correct this SQL code to make it not vulnerable?

Tags: python, sql, security, sqlite, sql-injection

I am having trouble trying to reformat this code so it is not vulnerable to SQL injection, any hints? I know it has something to do with the fact that you should create stored procedures instead and call these from python rather than dynamically constructing SQL but i do not know where to start. Thanks

```
handle[0].execute("insert into auditlog(userid, event, object)"
                  "  values({0}, '{1}', {2})".format(str(handle[2]),
                                             event, obj))
cursor.execute("select id, password from user where username='{0}'"
               .format(username))
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it has nothing to do with stored parameters. The answer is simply to use the DB-API's parameter functionality, rather than simple string substitution.

```
cursor.execute("insert into auditlog(userid, event, object) values(?, ?, ?)",
               (str(handle[2]), event, obj))

cursor.execute("select id, password from user where username=?"
               (username,))
```

(Note that adapters for other databases, such as MySQL, confusingly use `%s` instead of `?` as their placeholder; but you are still using a params tuple, not string substitution.)